# Convergence and accumulation points proof.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, converges to $A$ and $\{a_n: n \in J\}$ is an infinite set.  Show that $A$ is an accumulation point of $\{a_n: n \in J\}$.

So far I have done the basics of convergence but the accumulation point material is confusing to me.

So far I have:

If $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $A$, 
then $\exists \epsilon>0$, $N \in \mathbb N^+$ such that $\forall n>=N$ we have 
$|a_n-A| < \epsilon$.

Let S=$\{a_n: n \in J\}$...?

The definition I'm trying to use is:

> Let $S$ be a set of all real numbers. A real number $A$ is an accumulation point of $S$ iff every neighborhood of $A$ contains infinitely many points of $S$.

I feel like this should be easy for me to do but its not clicking yet.

This problem is #24 from the *Intro to Analysis* textbook by Edward D. Gaughan

Answer (score 3):

An accumulation point of a sequence is a more general concept that a limit. For example, the sequence $+1,-1,+1,-1,...$ has no limit, but two accumulation points, $\pm 1$.

(If you prefer to have distinct points, take the sequence $+1+\frac{1}{1},-1+\frac{1}{2},+1+\frac{1}{3},-1+\frac{1}{4},...$)

Think of accumulation points as limits of subsequences. A point is an accumulation point of a sequence **iff** you can find a subsequence converging to that point.

It should be clear that if $a_n \to A$, then **all** subsequences must also converge to $A$.

Suppose $J$ is an infinite set, and $U$ an open set containing $A$. Since $a_n \to A$, we have some $N$ such that $a_n \in U$ for all $n \ge N$. Then we see that the set $J'=J \cap \{N,N+1,...\}$ is also infinite (otherwise a quick contradiction), and for all $n \in J'$, $a_n \in U$. Hence $A$ is an accumulation point of the subsequence $a_n$, $n \in J$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'm actually starting to understand this better

Comment: Good luck! ${}{}{}$

Comment: I upvoted this answer, but I don't agree with your first example: $1$ and $-1$ are *cluster* points of the sequence, but *not* accumulation points of the set consisting of the terms of the sequence, at least according to the OP's definition

Comment: @egreg: I added a slightly modified sequence that should address your concern. I have seen varying definitions for limit, cluster, accumulation points of sets and sequences, and sometimes forget to read the germane fine print...

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, math terminology is not standardized. In this case using the term “accumulation” instead of “cluster” might confuse the OP.

Comment: @egreg: It would be very helpful if there were some sorts of standards, impossible though it would be to impose. As an example, some authors have separability as part of the definition of Hilbert space, so they can obtain strong results. If you skim their books looking for results you can stumble badly...